# How to print user's city name based off of geolocation

Tags: geolocation

What's the easiest way to print a user's city name on web page, without using 3rd party links like ipinfo.io ? Based off of their MAC Address? IP address doesn't always show correct city name...

Comment: A MAC address (Ethernet address) doesn't contain any location information. And it is usually not even available to Internet servers.

Comment: Either you rely on a third party, or you use [geolocation API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/Using_geolocation) (which in turn does often rely on a third party when running on desktop). But this asks for user permission. (You asked for "easiest", this is open to interpretation)